# User who has logged into the product on three separate days in at least one seven-day period

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe(df) for user engagement as follows :-

| time_stamp | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2013-01-01 10:05:23 | 1 |
| 2013-01-03 16:35:23 | 1 |
| 2013-01-06 11:06:35 | 1 |
| 2013-01-10 12:05:43 | 1 |
| 2013-01-11 13:32:12 | 2 |
| 2013-01-04 16:26:34 | 3 |
| 2013-01-05 14:02:51 | 3 |
| 2013-01-11 18:35:53 | 3 |
| 2013-01-04 12:26:34 | 4 |
| 2013-01-05 13:31:11 | 4 |
| 2013-01-12 17:35:52 | 4 |

Each row is a single login to the system. An adopted user is a user who has logged into the product on **three separate days** in **at least one seven-day period**. How do I find the user_ids of all adopted users?

Output is a list of user_ids for adopted users -
`user_list = ['1', '3']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use  [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for floor by days and then `groupby` with `rolling` by each 3 rows. But there is problem need numeric, so datetimes are converted to unix times:

```
df['time_stamp'] = df['time_stamp'].dt.floor('d').astype(np.int64)
#sorting and remove duplicated days per users 
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'time_stamp']).drop_duplicates()

a = df.groupby('user_id')['time_stamp'].rolling(window=3)
b = pd.to_timedelta((a.max()- a.min())).dt.days
print (b)
user_id    
1        0     NaN
         1     NaN
         2     5.0
         3     7.0
2        4     NaN
3        5     NaN
         6     NaN
         7     7.0
4        8     NaN
         9     NaN
         10    8.0
Name: time_stamp, dtype: float64

c = b[b == 7].index.get_level_values('user_id').tolist()
print (c)
[1, 3]
```

Comment: the output should also contain user_id '3' since this user has 3 logins between '2013-01-04' and '2013-01-11' which is a 7 day period, however, it should not contain user_id '4' since it is more than 7 days

Comment: we cannot use any start to the week since we are looking at rolling 7 days. The 3 logins can come from Tues to Mon or Sun to Sat, so ANY 7 days should count

Comment: Output should be 1,3  , user 4 is not included since it's 3 logins are in 8 day period, not in 7 days

Comment: but user 1 has 3 logins in 7 days so it is good! 4th login is after 7th day, it is minimum of 3 logins in any 7 days

Comment: this is good only change I will make is :-
c = b[b < 8].index.get_level_values('user_id').tolist()

since, it should count values less than 7 as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

provided `df` contains sample dataframe, I'm calculating and grouping by week number for given dates.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['ime_stamp'])

df['wk'] = df['ime_stamp'].dt.week
df = df.groupby(['wk','user_id'])['ime_stamp'].count().reset_index(name="freq")

result = df[df.freq >= 3]

# only user ids matching criteria
user_ids = result.user_id.tolist()
print(user_ids)
```

Output: `[1]`

```
# list of tuples containing user_id and number times logged in
p = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(result.user_id, result.freq) ]
print(p)
```

Output: `[(1, 3)]`

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in which days a user logged in we will need to first convert the timestamps with both a date and time component into a date. The easiest way is to use [dt.floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) to "round down" to the nearest day.

If we don't want to consider multiple logins on the same day (as is the case here), we need to exclude any duplicate user_id, date pairs. This can be easily achieved using [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with an optional subset. (The subset is optional here because there are no other columns, however, if there are more than these columns in a larger dataset the subset is required if only considering user_id and time_stamp.) We can keep all entries by skipping this step to consider every login regardless of if they log in multiple times in the same day.

Now, we need to obtain 7-day windows which can be easily achieved using [DataFrameGroupBy.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rolling.html) in conjunction with [DataFrameGroupBy.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html). We'll use this to calculate how many logins a user has had in the last 7 days for each login date. We'll use a window that is closed on both ends so that the 7th day is included in the window. The benefit of this approach is that we have an idiomatic representation of a rolling time window '7D' that can be easily defined or modified using [offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

Before we can do our rolling count, however, we need to make our time_stamp column a datetime index using [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [sort it](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html). A sorted DatetimeIndex is a prerequisite to be able to use a frequency based window for groupby rolling.

```
# Remove time information from timestamps (convert to date)
df['time_stamp'] = df['time_stamp'].dt.floor('d')
# Remove multiple instances of the same user on the same day
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id', 'time_stamp'])
# Create a datetime index and sort (required for groupby rolling on frequency window)
df = df.set_index('time_stamp').sort_index()
# Create a rolling window over 7 days per user and count number of login days
s = df.groupby('user_id')['user_id'].rolling(window='7D', closed='both').count()
# Here we have a Series which has a cumulative number of logins during the window
print(s)
```

Which results in:

```
user_id  time_stamp
1        2013-01-01    1.0
         2013-01-03    2.0
         2013-01-06    3.0
         2013-01-10    3.0
2        2013-01-11    1.0
3        2013-01-04    1.0
         2013-01-05    2.0
         2013-01-11    3.0
4        2013-01-04    1.0
         2013-01-05    2.0
         2013-01-12    2.0
Name: user_id, dtype: float64
```

Note here that for every day a user logged in (index level 1) we can also see the number of times they've logged in in the previous 7 days.

Looking at user_id 1, we can see that they met the "logged in 3 days in a 7-day window" metric on two separate days. Once on 2013-01-06 (logins on 2013-01-01, 2013-01-03, and 2013-01-06) and then again on 2013-01-10 (logins in 2013-01-03, 2013-01-06, and 2013-01-10). Notice also that the count remained 3 when moving from 2013-01-06 to 2013-01-10 because 2013-01-01 fell out of the 7-day window.

---

From this summary information (`s`), we can derive any additional information we need. We can filter to see where the count is greater than or equal to 3. Which would give us every user and the date on which they met the criteria of having logged in on at least 3 separate days within a 7-day window.

```
s[s.ge(3)]
```

```
user_id  time_stamp
1        2013-01-06    3.0
         2013-01-10    3.0
3        2013-01-11    3.0
Name: user_id, dtype: float64
```

If we just care about the list of user_ids, we can just get the [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.unique.html) values and [make it a list](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_list.html)

```
s[s.ge(3)].index.unique('user_id').to_list()
```

```
[1, 3]
```

---

Complete working example with setup, imports, and versions:

```
import pandas as pd  # version 2.1.1

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time_stamp': pd.to_datetime([
        '2013-01-01 10:05:23', '2013-01-03 16:35:23', '2013-01-06 11:06:35',
        '2013-01-10 12:05:43', '2013-01-11 13:32:12', '2013-01-11 14:58:19',
        '2013-01-04 16:26:34', '2013-01-05 14:02:51', '2013-01-11 18:35:53',
        '2013-01-04 12:26:34', '2013-01-05 13:31:11', '2013-01-12 17:35:52'
    ]),
    'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
})

# Series constructed from chained methods instead of separate lines 
s = (
    df.assign(time_stamp=df['time_stamp'].dt.floor('d'))
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id', 'time_stamp'])
    .set_index('time_stamp').sort_index()
    .groupby('user_id')['user_id'].rolling(window='7D', closed='both').count()
)

# Grab just the unique list of user ids
print(s[s.ge(3)].index.unique('user_id').to_list())
```